# android share images from assets folder

Tags: android, image, share, assets

I'm trying to share an image from my assets folder. My code is:

```
Intent share = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
share.setType("image/jpg");
share.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, Uri.parse("file:///assets/myImage.jpg"));
startActivity(Intent.createChooser(share, "Share This Image"));
```

but it doesn't work. Do you have any ideas?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Complementing what [@intrepidis](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12651214/3356513) answered:

You will need override methods like example class above:

```
package com.android.example;

import android.content.ContentProvider;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.content.res.AssetFileDescriptor;
import android.content.res.AssetManager;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.database.Cursor;
import java.io.IOException;
import android.os.CancellationSignal;

public class AssetsProvider extends ContentProvider
{

        @Override
        public AssetFileDescriptor openAssetFile( Uri uri, String mode ) throws FileNotFoundException
        {
                Log.v( TAG, "AssetsGetter: Open asset file" );
                AssetManager am = getContext( ).getAssets( );
                String file_name = uri.getLastPathSegment( );
                if( file_name == null )
                        throw new FileNotFoundException( );
                AssetFileDescriptor afd = null;
                try
                {
                        afd = am.openFd( file_name );
                }
                catch(IOException e)
                {
                        e.printStackTrace( );
                }
                return afd;//super.openAssetFile(uri, mode);
        }

        @Override
        public String getType( Uri p1 )
        {
                // TODO: Implement this method
                return null;
        }

        @Override
        public int delete( Uri p1, String p2, String[] p3 )
        {
                // TODO: Implement this method
                return 0;
        }

        @Override
        public Cursor query( Uri p1, String[] p2, String p3, String[] p4, String p5 )
        {
                // TODO: Implement this method
                return null;
        }

        @Override
        public Cursor query( Uri uri, String[] projection, String selection, String[] selectionArgs, String sortOrder, CancellationSignal cancellationSignal )
        {
                // TODO: Implement this method
                return super.query( uri, projection, selection, selectionArgs, sortOrder, cancellationSignal );
        }

        @Override
        public Uri insert( Uri p1, ContentValues p2 )
        {
                // TODO: Implement this method
                return null;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onCreate( )
        {
                // TODO: Implement this method
                return false;
        }

        @Override
        public int update( Uri p1, ContentValues p2, String p3, String[] p4 )
        {
                // TODO: Implement this method
                return 0;
        }
}
```

I needed to override two times the query method.
And add these lines above tag  in your androidmanifest.xml:

```
<provider
  android:name="com.android.example.AssetsProvider"
  android:authorities="com.android.example"
  android:grantUriPermissions="true"
  android:exported="true" />
```

And with this, all work like a charm :D

Comment: can someone please help me i am getting images from assets---->folder---->image1.png   and i am failed to get images from assets subfolder pls suggest me code editing of this line  String file_name = uri.getLastPathSegment( );

Comment: Sorry for my late. How you send the file to intent? I think the code is alright. You need   call image by addres like this: file:///android_asset/folder/image1.png

If you need share this, you need to use this code:
String file = "folder/image1.png";
Uri theUri = Uri.parse( "content://com.example.yourproject/" + file );
Intent theIntent = new Intent( Intent.ACTION_SEND );
theIntent.setType( "image/*" );
theIntent.putExtra( Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, theUri );
startActivity( Intent.createChooser( theIntent, "Send to:" );

Comment: @Kikuto actually, if you have subfolders in your assets, then you should change AssetsProvider openAssetFile  method file_name to String file_name = uri.getPath().substring(1, uri.getPath().length());

Answer (score 18):

It is possible to share files (images including) from the assets folder through a custom `ContentProvider`

You need to extend `ContentProvider`, register it in your manifest and implement the `openAssetFile` method.  You can then assess the assets via `Uri`s

```
    @Override
    public AssetFileDescriptor openAssetFile(Uri uri, String mode) throws FileNotFoundException {
        AssetManager am = getContext().getAssets();
        String file_name = uri.getLastPathSegment();

        if(file_name == null) 
            throw new FileNotFoundException();
        AssetFileDescriptor afd = null;
        try {
            afd = am.openFd(file_name);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return afd;
    }
```

Comment: can you add some more details of how can we call this from another application?

Answer (score 14):

This blog explains it all:
http://nowherenearithaca.blogspot.co.uk/2012/03/too-easy-using-contentprovider-to-send.html

Basically, this goes in the manifest:

```
<provider android:name="yourclass.that.extendsContentProvider"                android:authorities="com.yourdomain.whatever"/>
```

The content provider class has this:

```
@Override
public AssetFileDescriptor openAssetFile(Uri uri, String mode) throws FileNotFoundException {
    AssetManager am = getContext().getAssets();
    String file_name = uri.getLastPathSegment();
    if(file_name == null) 
        throw new FileNotFoundException();
    AssetFileDescriptor afd = null;
    try {
        afd = am.openFd(file_name);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return afd;//super.openAssetFile(uri, mode);
}
```

And the calling code does this:

```
Uri theUri = Uri.parse("content://com.yourdomain.whatever/someFileInAssetsFolder");
Intent theIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
theIntent.setType("image/*");
theIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM,theUri);
theIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT,"Subject for message");                        
theIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "Body for message");
startActivity(theIntent);
```

Comment: Make sure the URI begins with "content://"

Comment: I'm getting "java.io.FileNotFoundException: This file can not be opened as a file descriptor; it is probably compressed" on the am.openFd(file_name)

Comment: @GozzoMan For you, what is the actual value of the `file_name` variable when debugging?

Answer (score 5):

Since none of the other answers here worked for me (in 2019) I made a workaround by copying the asset to the app's internal file directory and then sharing this file. 
In my case, I needed to share a pdf file from the assets folder.

In the AndroidManifest.xml add a file provider (no need to use a custom one):

```
<provider
    android:name="androidx.core.content.FileProvider"
    android:authorities="${applicationId}.provider"
    android:exported="false"
    android:grantUriPermissions="true">
    <meta-data
        android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
        android:resource="@xml/filepaths" />
</provider>
```

Create a filepaths.xml file in res/xml/

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<paths>
    <files-path
        name="root"
        path="/" />
</paths>
```

Of course you should use a subdirectory here if you manage other files in your app directory.

Now in the class where you want to trigger the share intent.

**1. Create an empty file in the files directory**

```
private fun createFileInFilesDir(filename: String): File {
    val file = File(filesDir.path + "/" + filename)
    if (file.exists()) {
        if (!file.delete()) {
            throw IOException()
        }
    }
    if (!file.createNewFile()) {
        throw IOException()
    }
    return file
}
```

**2. Copy the content of the asset to the file**

```
private fun copyAssetToFile(assetName: String, file: File) {
    val buffer = ByteArray(1024)
    val inputStream = assets.open(assetName)
    val outputStream: OutputStream = FileOutputStream(file)
    while (inputStream.read(buffer) > 0) {
        outputStream.write(buffer)
    }
}
```

**3. Create a share intent for the file**

```
private fun createIntentForFile(file: File, intentAction: String): Intent {
    val uri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(this, applicationContext.packageName + ".provider", file)
    val intent = Intent(intentAction)
    intent.flags = Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION
    intent.setDataAndType(uri, "application/pdf")
    return intent
}
```

**4. Execute 1-3 and fire the intent**

```
private fun sharePdfAsset(assetName: String, intentAction: String) {
    try {
        val file = createFileInFilesDir(assetName)
        copyAssetToFile(assetName, file)
        val intent = createIntentForFile(file, intentAction)
        startActivity(Intent.createChooser(intent, null))
    } catch (e: IOException) {
        e.printStackTrace()
        AlertDialog.Builder(this)
            .setTitle(R.string.error)
            .setMessage(R.string.share_error)
            .show()
    }
}
```

**5. Call the function**

```
sharePdfAsset("your_pdf_asset.pdf", Intent.ACTION_SEND)
```

If you want to delete the file after sharing it, you probably could use `startActivityForResult()` and delete it afterwards. By changing the `intentAction` you can also use this process for an "open with..." action by using `Intent.ACTION_VIEW`.
For `assets`, `filesDir`, ... you need to be in an `Activity` or have a `Context` of course.

Answer (score 4):

Many apps require you to provide name and size of the image. So here is an improved code (using Google's FileProvider code as an example):

```
public class AssetsProvider extends ContentProvider {

    private final static String LOG_TAG = AssetsProvider.class.getName();

    private static final String[] COLUMNS = {
            OpenableColumns.DISPLAY_NAME, OpenableColumns.SIZE };

    @Override
    public boolean onCreate() {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public Cursor query(Uri uri, String[] projection, String selection, String[] selectionArgs, String sortOrder) {
        /**
         * Source: {@link FileProvider#query(Uri, String[], String, String[], String)} .
         */
        if (projection == null) {
            projection = COLUMNS;
        }

        final AssetManager am = getContext().getAssets();
        final String path = getRelativePath(uri);
        long fileSize = 0;
        try {
            final AssetFileDescriptor afd = am.openFd(path);
            fileSize = afd.getLength();
            afd.close();
        } catch(IOException e) {
            Log.e(LOG_TAG, "Can't open asset file", e);
        }

        final String[] cols = new String[projection.length];
        final Object[] values = new Object[projection.length];
        int i = 0;
        for (String col : projection) {
            if (OpenableColumns.DISPLAY_NAME.equals(col)) {
                cols[i] = OpenableColumns.DISPLAY_NAME;
                values[i++] = uri.getLastPathSegment();
            } else if (OpenableColumns.SIZE.equals(col)) {
                cols[i] = OpenableColumns.SIZE;
                values[i++] = fileSize;
            }
        }

        final MatrixCursor cursor = new MatrixCursor(cols, 1);
        cursor.addRow(values);
        return cursor;
    }

    @Override
    public String getType(Uri uri) {
        /**
         * Source: {@link FileProvider#getType(Uri)} .
         */
        final String file_name = uri.getLastPathSegment();
        final int lastDot = file_name.lastIndexOf('.');
        if (lastDot >= 0) {
            final String extension = file_name.substring(lastDot + 1);
            final String mime = MimeTypeMap.getSingleton().getMimeTypeFromExtension(extension);
            if (mime != null) {
                return mime;
            }
        }

        return "application/octet-stream";
    }

    @Override
    public Uri insert(Uri uri, ContentValues values) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public int delete(Uri uri, String selection, String[] selectionArgs) {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public int update(Uri uri, ContentValues values, String selection, String[] selectionArgs) {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public AssetFileDescriptor openAssetFile(Uri uri, String mode) throws FileNotFoundException {
        final AssetManager am = getContext().getAssets();
        final String path = getRelativePath(uri);
        if(path == null) {
            throw new FileNotFoundException();
        }
        AssetFileDescriptor afd = null;
        try {
            afd = am.openFd(path);
        } catch(IOException e) {
            Log.e(LOG_TAG, "Can't open asset file", e);
        }
        return afd;
    }

    private String getRelativePath(Uri uri) {
        String path = uri.getPath();
        if (path.charAt(0) == '/') {
            path = path.substring(1);
        }
        return path;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

AFAIK, there's no way to share an image from the `assets` folder. But it's possible to share resources from the `res` folder.

Comment: can you give me a example how to share images from drawable folder from resources?

Comment: The format is: `android.resource://[package]/[type]/[id]`. So, an URI example is: `"android.resource://com.your.app/drawable/" + Integer.toStrng(R.drawable.some_resource)`.

Comment: I've tried using 
share.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, Uri.parse("android.resource://com.packake.myapp/drawable/" + Integer.toString(R.drawable.myimage))); it works sharing it with gmail but when trying to share it with yahoo mail I get the message "Read access denied. Resource cannot be read". do you have any ideea why?

Comment: I think it depends on how an app handles this kind of URIs.

Comment: @Pixie It is possible, please see my answer.

Comment: @smith324 Writing your own `ContentProvider` must be a working solution but is sharing an image worth doing it? I think it's much easier to put this image to `res/drawable-nodpi` folder.

Comment: @Pixie Depends on the application, you may need to share from the assests with more than just an image

Comment: @smith324 Maybe. But as for me it's not a practical problem. However it doesn't make your solution bad. +1

Answer (score 1):

To share from assets folder I can only recommend the [cwac-provider](https://github.com/commonsguy/cwac-provider) library (StreamProvider).

Among avoiding to develop your own content provider, it adds some support for capricious legacy apps (check `USE_LEGACY_CURSOR_WRAPPER`).

Comment: Discontinued :(