# Share image with other apps

Tags: android, image, share

Here is my problem... I want to share a png image. I have the image in drawable and assets. When I use the sharingIntent it works but not in the way that I want. The file shared appears with numbers and without extension and some apps send the message "unknow file". What can i do??

this is my code:

```
    Uri uri = Uri.parse("android.resource://com.example.shareimages/" + R.drawable.caja);
    Intent shareIntent = new Intent();
    shareIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);

    shareIntent.setType("image/png");

    shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM,  uri);

    startActivity(Intent.createChooser(shareIntent, "send"));
```

I tried to use instead of drawable files, the files in assets ( with this "**file:///android_asset/...**) but it didn't work

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
Intent shareIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
shareIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_WHEN_TASK_RESET);
shareIntent.setType("image/*");

// For a file in shared storage.  For data in private storage, use a ContentProvider.
Uri uri = Uri.fromFile(getFileStreamPath(pathToImage));
shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, uri);
startActivity(shareIntent)
```

If you want to share it via the assets folder, you'll have to use a ContentProvider. See this answer on how to do so:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/7177103/1369222

Comment: hummm the problem is in the path: 12-18 23:47:45.554: E/AndroidRuntime(26896): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
12-18 23:47:45.554: E/AndroidRuntime(26896): java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: File android.resource://com.example.shareimages/2130837505 contains a path separator     what path should use?

Comment: you are sharing from internal storage. For internal storage, you'll have to use Content Provider. I have mentioned this in the answer.

Comment: amm sorry thats true...thanks for the help and patience :) ill try the Content Provider