# Sharing failed while sharing Firebase image URI to other apps?

Tags: java, android, android-studio

While sharing image URI to other sharing is getting failed. So I want a solution on how to share my app images to other app using bluetooth, whatsapp etc.

Here is my code:

```
ArrayList <Uri> imageUri = new ArrayList<>();

for (int i = 0; i < urimodel.size(); i++) {
 Uri model_uri = urimodel.get(i); //getting uri from here

 imageUri.add(model_uri);

 Intent shareIntent = new Intent();
 shareIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND_MULTIPLE);
 shareIntent.putParcelableArrayListExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, imageUri);
 shareIntent.setType("image/*");
 context.startActivity(Intent.createChooser(shareIntent, "Share images to.."));
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My suggestion first save image which u want to share then pass uri

Ref : [Share Image with Other Apps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13945919/share-image-with-other-apps)

Try something Like this

```
Intent shareIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
shareIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_WHEN_TASK_RESET);
shareIntent.setType("image/*");

// For a file in shared storage.  For data in private storage, use a ContentProvider.
Uri uri = Uri.fromFile(getFileStreamPath(pathToImage));
shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, uri);
startActivity(shareIntent)
```

If you want to share it via the assets folder, you'll have to use a ContentProvider. See this answer on how to do so:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/7177103/1369222

> **OR**

Add File Provider in Android Manifest

```
<provider
android:name="android.support.v4.content.FileProvider"
android:grantUriPermissions="true"
android:exported="false"
android:authorities="${applicationId}">

<meta-data
    android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
    android:resource="@xml/file_provider_paths"/>
```

> file_provider_paths.xml

```
<paths>
    <cache-path name="cache" path="/" />
    <files-path name=”files” path=”/” />
</paths>
```

See That [How to use support FileProvider for sharing content to other apps?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18249007/how-to-use-support-fileprovider-for-sharing-content-to-other-apps)

Answer (score 1):

this must be because your  firebase storage setting didn't allow to read and write without auth

just go to to storage>rules and change the rules with this

```
service firebase.storage {
  match /b/{bucket}/o {
    match /{allPaths=**} {
      allow read;
      allow write: if request.auth != null;
    }
  }
}
```

this will allow everyone can read your image

**Warning reading and writing the storage database also count and you need to pay cost to remain it work after certain limit.** check pricing [here](https://firebase.google.com/pricing/)

[image: example]

Comment: thanks for sharing your experience truely i'm unaware about pricing .

Comment: Welcome @Ahsan.