# Obtain the drawable image according ID

Tags: android, imageview, viewflipper

I have the following code:

Layout :

```
<ViewFlipper android:id="@+id/viewFlipper"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:layout_width="fill_parent" >

<include layout="@layout/imagen3"/>

<include layout="@layout/imagen2"/>
```

Example layout imagen3 :

```
    <ImageView
    android:id="@+id/preview"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/fondo3"/>
```

Java :

```
    Uri imageUri = Uri.parse("android.resource://" + getPackageName()
                    + "/drawable/" + "preview");
```

I want to create ImageURI with the id of the imageview.

Comment: because I want to share the image, the problem is that now I can only share the imagen2 which is what I put in Uri, example:
   Uri imageUri = Uri.parse ("android.resource: //" + getPackageName ()
                     + "/ Drawable /" + "imagen2");

Comment: I don't think that this is good idea because drawable is in [INTERNAL STORAGE](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#filesInternal) so another application do not have access to this memory. My advice is copy your image to [EXTERNAL STORAGE](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#filesExternal)

Comment: You mean you get the image URL Internet?

Answer (score 2):

I don't think that this is a good idea because drawable is in [internal storage](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#filesInternal) so another application do not have access to this memory.

First you could make a copy of your image to [external storage](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#filesExternal)

Or EVEN BETTER create [Content Provider](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/content-provider-creating.html). This is the most correct and secure way in android to share content. Look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29477209/android-sending-image-from-assets-folder-using-content-provider) for example.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the R index for it (so you can use it) by using it's ID.  Like this:

```
Integer imageIs =  getImageViewResource(R.id.preview)
```

The you can do more things with it, like change the image:

```
setImageViewResource(R.id.preview, newImage)
```

Why you would ever want to set that to a URI as a mystery...

Answer (score 0):

The problem is not whether internal or external, because it works correctly with the internal images, the problem is I want to use the same code to a different drawable corresponding to each image