# Android PDF from Assets folder

Tags: android, android-intent, android-file, androidpdfviewer

I want to open a pdf file from the assets folder by clicking a button. Tried the below code but it's not working.

```
 btn_help.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        String uriPath = "file:///android_asset/Guide.pdf";
                        Uri uri = Uri.parse(uriPath);
                        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
                        intent.setDataAndType(uri, "application/pdf");
                        startActivity(intent);


                    }
                });
```

Comment: You should use a content provider dat can serve files from assets. It has been published on github and is named AssetsProvider. Hope that is enough for you to find the beast.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29477209/android-sending-image-from-assets-folder-using-content-provider

Comment: @blackapps Please help me to call assetprovider from my activity. I used like below but it's not working.                                new  AssetsProvider().openAssetFile(Uri.parse("file:///android_asset/eDVIRGuide.pdf"),null);

Answer (score 0):

I believe you can use [PDF Viewer library](https://github.com/barteksc/AndroidPdfViewerV2) .

Through this library you can use `pdfView.fromAsset()` builder.