# Share an image from drawable or web url on Twitter

Tags: android, twitter

I'm trying to share an image on twitter from the application drawable resources. I've also tried supplying a URL for the image on my server, but the result was the same.

Please note that when the tweetcomposer is open, it does show the image, but when I click the tweet button an error is displayed in the logcat.
The documentations states:

> The image Uri should be a Uri using the content:// scheme.

https://dev.twitter.com/twitterkit/android/compose-tweets

What do I need to change in the code in order to get this done?

```
Uri uri = Uri.parse("android.resource://" + getPackageName() + "/drawable/some_image");
final Intent intent = new ComposerActivity.Builder(MainActivity.this)
                         .session(session)
                         .image(uri)
                         .text("This is atest!")
                         .hashtags("#testest")
                         .createIntent();
startActivity(intent);
```

The tweet failed with this message:

> Post Tweet failed
>
> > com.twitter.sdk.android.core.TwitterException: Uri file path resolved to null
> >                                                                                       at com.twitter.sdk.android.tweetcomposer.TweetUploadService.uploadMedia(TweetUploadService.java:125)
> >                                                                                       at com.twitter.sdk.android.tweetcomposer.TweetUploadService.uploadTweet(TweetUploadService.java:84)
> >                                                                                       at com.twitter.sdk.android.tweetcomposer.TweetUploadService.onHandleIntent(TweetUploadService.java:79)
> >                                                                                       at android.app.IntentService$ServiceHandler.handleMessage(IntentService.java:68)
> >                                                                                       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
> >                                                                                       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
> >                                                                                       at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:61)

Comment: You should use a content provider to serve your image from drawables.

Comment: I actually tried this solution, https://stackoverflow.com/a/12651214/500105
as before the image is shown, but after clicking tweet the same eror message is displayed.